# Referring to a list box value in Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox

I have a sql query in access which result it being transferred to a list box in an Access form.
What I need to do is insert the values from my form to an access table, for which I am using the following code in VBA:

```
sSQL = "INSERT INTO MainTable ([IndxLvl], [POF_Pluquo], [Actual_Shipped], [Buffer], [Do_Something], [Controlled], [Overstock]) VALUES (9, Forms![Form_helper].LVL9POF.Value, Forms![Form_helper].LVL9SHIPPED.Value, Forms![Form_helper].Buffer9.Value, 14, 36, 50)"
DoCmd.RunSQL sSQL
```

The name of the List Box is Buffer9, so I am referring to the value in the list box with:

```
Forms![Form_helper].Buffer9.Value
```

This line of code works for all of the values I have in other text boxes.
I do realize that this is not a text box, but a list box and I guess there is another way of referring to the value in this object.

Comment: What does `sSQL`  equal before you run the SQL?  Step through the code using F8

Comment: When I step through the code and before I go through the DoCmd.RunSQL sSQL,
sSQL = the value in the string, the text itself:
"INSERT INTO MainTable ([IndxLvl], [POF_Pluquo], [Actual_Shipped], [Buffer], [Do_Something], [Controlled], [Overstock]) VALUES (9, Forms![Form_helper].LVL9POF.Value, Forms![Form_helper].LVL9SHIPPED.Value, Forms![Form_helper].Buffer9.Value, 14, 36, 50)"

Comment: You need to break it up and put the values in, like `"INSERT INTO MainTable ([IndxLvl], [POF_Pluquo], [Actual_Shipped], [Buffer], [Do_Something], [Controlled], [Overstock]) VALUES (9, " & Forms![Form_helper].LVL9POF.Value & "," & Forms![Form_helper].` etc

Comment: Why not data entry via form bound to MainTable? Referencing listbox within quote mark delimited string works for me. DoCmd.RunSQL can handle this. If use CurrentDb.Execute, would have to concatenate control references. In either, Listbox cannot be multi-select.

Comment: So what happens - error message, wrong result, nothing?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav , I have tried with the quotes

 sSQL = "INSERT INTO MainTable ([IndxLvl], [POF_Pluquo], [Actual_Shipped], [Buffer], [Do_Something], [Controlled], [Overstock]) VALUES (9, " & Forms![Form_helper].LVL9POF.Value & "," & Forms![Form_helper].LVL9SHIPPED.Value & "," & Forms![Form_helper].Buffer9.Value & ", 14,36,50)" 

But unfortunately I am getting an error message:  Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. Sorry about the way the code looks, not sure how to paste in a comment looking as a code block

Comment: can you post what sSQL equates to afterwards please, as i dont have your form.

Comment: sSQL = `"INSERT INTO MainTable ([IndxLvl], [POF_Pluquo], [Actual_Shipped], [Buffer], [Do_Something], [Controlled], [Overstock]) VALUES (9, 12019993,12020046,, 14,36,50)"`

After 12020046 there should be a value = 53. This value is coming out of a ListBox and not a Text Box, because I could not assign the query that gave me that value to a text box for whatever reason

Comment: Is anything selected in Buffer9?

Comment: Yes, there is a value in list box named Buffer9

Comment: What does the value of `debug.print Forms![Form_helper].Buffer9.Value` equal before you execute the sql statement?  can you share some info about the listbox?

Comment: It gives me Null, when I run the debug.print command. The way I linked the list box with the query result is from the Form -> Design View -> click on the list box and go in the property sheet in Data tab -> Row Source. I have link the row source with the sql query result

Comment: By the way, thank you for sticking my problem for so long now

Comment: Did you see my earlier comment?